# Show the statement: $ (X\setminus A)\cap \partial A=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow X\setminus A \text{ open}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $ A\subseteq X $. I tried to show$ (X\setminus A)\cap \partial A=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow X\setminus A \text{  open}$

I have no idea how to proof both directions: $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$.

For $\Leftarrow$ I only have this: For all $ x\in X\setminus A $ there is an $ \varepsilon>0 $ such that $ B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subseteq X\setminus A $. Then I assume $ (X\setminus A)\cap \partial A\neq \emptyset $. From here I get stuck.

$\Rightarrow$: I want to show: for all $ x\in X\setminus A$ there exists $ \varepsilon > 0 $ such that $ B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subseteq X\setminus A $. I don't know how can I find $ \varepsilon $ if I only know the last information.

Comment: When you assume $(X\setminus A)\cap \partial A\neq \emptyset$, this gives you a point $y$ both in $X \setminus A$ and in $\partial A$. This should lead you to a contradiction when you expand the definition of $\partial A$ and consider the opennes of $X \setminus A$.

Comment: Ok, when I expand $ \partial A $ then I get from my current knowledge: $ \partial A=\partial (X\setminus A)=\overline{(X\setminus A)}\setminus (X\setminus A)^°=\overline{(X\setminus A)}\setminus (X\setminus A) $.

I assumed $ (X\setminus A)\cap \partial A\neq \emptyset $ which means there is $ z\in X $ with $ z\in X\setminus A $ and $ z\in \partial A=\overline{(X\setminus A)}\setminus (X\setminus A) $ which means that $ z\in \overline{(X\setminus A)} $ and $ z \notin X\setminus A $ which is indeed a contradiction.

Comment: You could write $B = X \setminus A,$ so $\partial A = \partial B,$
$$
B \cap \partial B = B \cap (\overline{B} \setminus B^\circ) =
B \setminus B^\circ,
$$
and
$$
B \setminus B^\circ = \emptyset \iff B \subseteq B^\circ \iff
B \text{ is open.}
$$

Comment: @calum-gilhooley Please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I hesitate to post it as an answer, because it addresses only the OP's second paragraph, not the third or fourth. I feel an answer should aim to get the OP "unstuck", not just provide a proof for reference. (There's a perpetual tension over this sort of thing in Maths.SE, and I don't know the answer!)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $B_\varepsilon(x) \subseteq X \setminus A$ if and only if $B_\varepsilon(x) \cap A = \varnothing$. Also, recall that the definition of $\partial A$.

Answer (score 1):

For "=>" you can do it by contradiction again. Assuming $X \setminus A$ is *not* open means there's a $x \in X \setminus A$ where $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ contains a point outside of $X \setminus A$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.
Build a sequence of such points $\{ y_i \in A \}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ - for example, shrink $\varepsilon$ every time by 2 and take $y_i \in B_{2^{-i}}\,(x)$.

Now you have a sequence *outside* of $X \setminus A$ which converges to a point *inside* $X \setminus A$. Do you see how this (almost) completes the proof?

Answer (score 1):

$\partial A = \partial (X\setminus A)$ and for any set $B$, $B$ is open iff it is disjoint from its boundary:

If $B \cap \partial B = \emptyset$ then all points of $B$ are interior points (or else they'd be boundary points, which cannot happen).

And if $B$ is open then $\partial B = \overline{B}\setminus \operatorname{int}(B) = \overline{B}\setminus B$ is by definition disjoint from $B$.